# Checking for an optional header in a SignalR hub

Tags: http-headers, signalr, signalr-hub

In a SignalR hub method, `Context.Headers` provides a `INameValueCollection` with the request headers. `INameValueCollection` has just three members:

```cs
    string this[string key] { get; }
    string Get(string key);
    IEnumerable<string> GetValues(string key);
```

Unfortunately, none of them are documented. If you want to get a header but not throw an exception if it doesn't exist, what do you use? I'm guessing `Get`, but it sure would be nice if the author had bothered to document these details.

One thing I like about the "old" Microsoft was that even if a bit verbose, its documentation covered nearly all the semantics. SignalR was a wonderful, rapid development, but it would be even better if it retained that old-school diligence.

Perhaps I'm missing something. Are the semantics documented somewhere? Or does someone know and care to document them here as a quick and dirty workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem and in the end I looked it up in [the github source](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/3a219c101587333d562f04f30903d50ad9773e1c/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests.Common/Infrastructure/NameValueCollectionWrapper.cs) which takes you [System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

(there are other implementation of `INameValueCollection` as well but the one linked seems to be used in the request)

In short:

```
string this[string key] { get; }
string Get(string key);
```

> A String that contains the comma-separated list of values associated with the specified key, if found; otherwise, null.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetValues(string key);
```

> A String array that contains the values associated with the specified key from the NameValueCollection, if found; otherwise, null.